# How To Display Random Results in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to display 2 or more unique random results from a text file, How do I do that please?

But I need unique results and not 2 or more of the same.

Currently using this code, but it only returns 1 random result:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('flatFileDB.txt');
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);
$randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);
$randPhrase = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];
?>
<?php echo $randPhrase ?>
```

Comment: Use the same go get another random number, and then check it must be different from first one, if its not then do the same again

Comment: This, it's not that hard.  you're like 99% of the way there.   use those booleans and a very simple loop (or, ya know, just do it twice and assign a different name instead of putting it into an array of size... 1.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like that

```
shuffle($textArray);
    echo $textArray[0];
    echo $textArray[1];
```

http://php.net/manual/tr/function.shuffle.php

Comment: A simple and elegant solution that does no more and no less than asked for.

Comment: Yep, it did the job! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can give a shot to this also. Code is not tested. I am collecting the used into an array, and check, is that used before.

```
$text = file_get_contents('flatFileDB.txt');
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);
$used = array();
$countOfRandoms = 2;
$randoms = array();
$i = 1;
do {
    if ($countOfRandoms == $i) {
        break;
    }
    $randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);
    if (in_array($randArrayIndexNum, $used)) {
        continue;
    }
    $used[]  = $randArrayIndexNum;
    $random = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];
    $i++;
} while (true);
```

Comment: Yep, it did the job! Many Thanks!